# Opauth and Codeigniter Fatal error: Cannot access empty property

Tags: codeigniter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I use library [Opauth](http://opauth.org/) for social authentification. 
At the time of authorization slips error

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /%my_directory%/system/core/Loader.php on line 1095

Please tell me what this error is related.

It's **ci_opauth.php**

```
 $config['opauth_config'] = array(
            'path' => '/oauth/login/', //example: /ci_opauth/auth/login/
            'callback_url' => '/oauth/authenticate/', //example: /ci_opauth/auth/authenticate/
            'callback_transport' => 'post', //Codeigniter don't use native session
            'security_salt' => 'Salt',
            'debug' => false,
            'Strategy' => array( //comment those you don't use
                                'Twitter' => array(
                                'key' => 'key',
                                'secret' = 'secret_key',
                    'name' => 'Twitter',
                    'description' => 'Войти с помощью twitter.com',
                    'tabimg' => "<img src=/assets/img/social-buttons/blank.gif width=16px height=16px style='background-position: 0 476px';>",
                    'signinimg' => "<img src=/assets/img/social-buttons/blank.gif width=89px height=21px style='background-position: 0 -42px';>"
                                                 )
                                       )
                                             )
                                           );
```

it's **oauth.php**

```
public function login(){
        //Comprobate if the user request a strategy
        if($this->uri->segment(3)==''){
            $ci_config = $this->config->item('opauth_config');
            $arr_strategies = array_keys($ci_config['Strategy']);

            echo("Please, select an Oauth provider:<br />");
            echo("<ul>");
            foreach($arr_strategies AS $strategy){
                echo("<li><a href='".base_url()."oauth/login/".strtolower($strategy)."'>Login with ".$strategy."</li>");
            }
            echo("</ul>");
        }   
        else{
            //Run login
            $this->load->library('Opauth/Opauth', $this->config->item('opauth_config'), false);
            $this->opauth->run();    
        }     
    }

    function authenticate(){
        //Create authenticate logic
        $response = unserialize(base64_decode( $_POST['opauth'] ));
        echo("<pre>");
        print_r($response);
        echo("</pre>");
    }
```

If you need to provide more information, for answer my question, please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can use classic `require` if loader don't work :

```
require(APPPATH .'libraries/Opauth/Opauth.php');

$opauth = new Opauth($this->config->item('opauth_config'));
```

Comment: `require('application/libraries/Opauth/Opauth.php');
$opauth = new Opauth($this->config->item('opauth_config'));
$opauth->run();`

It did not help or I did something wrong?

Comment: You have an error or something else ? Considering you are not using CodeIgniter Loader anymore, you should have a different behavior.

Comment: Ok but now the include works. It a Opauth library problem. You shouldn't show your client key and ID. Please be sure of your config, and Opauth library version.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded the latest version Codeigniter framework and openauth downloaded from here https://github.com/destinomultimedia/ci_opauth, did integration and put on mine hosting. The same result. What is there may be a bug ...